# why does my prime number checker program always say the number is prime?

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make a program where the user inputs a number and it checks to see if its prime but no matter what you enter it says its prime. How do I fix this code?

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2: return False
    for x in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True

def main():
    keep_going='y'
    while keep_going=='y':
        n=int(input("Please enter a number to see if it's prime: "))
        is_prime(n)
        if True:
            print("It's prime")
        if False:
            print("it's not prime")
        keep_going=input("would you like to see if another number is prime? (y/n):")

main()
```

Comment: Are there supposed to be two `*` in `for x in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):`?

Comment: @Geshode: Yes, primality test usually checks numbers up to the square root of N, and square root of N is equivalent to raising N to the power of 0.5 - thus exponentiation operator `**`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this

`while keep_going=='y':
        n=int(input("Please enter a number to see if it's prime: "))
          if is_prime(n):
            print("It's prime")
        else:
            print("it's not prime")
        keep_going=input("would you like to see if another number is prime? (y/n):")`

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the return value of `is_prime(n)` anywhere, and you are not testing this return value. `if True:` is unconditional execution. `if False:` is unconditional non-execution.

Instead, you want to test `is_prime(n)`:

```
if is_prime(n):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

or

```
prime = is_prime(n)
if prime:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

The good news is - your `is_prime` function is correct, and does return `False` for non-prime numbers as it should :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    elif n % (n // 2) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    keep_going = 'y'
    while keep_going == 'y':
        n = int(input("Please enter a number to see if it's prime: "))
        if is_prime(n):
            print("It's prime")
        else:
            print("it's not prime")
        keep_going = input("would you like to see if another number is prime?(y/n):")


main()
```